# Browse for a file and place the data in the text box

Tags: vb.net

when i click the "browse" button I need to browse for a txt/xml file and place the data of that file in the text box.So for this I tried with a code but I was not successful.So can you help me with the vb.net code for this

Comment: "So for this I tried with a code but I was not successful" would mean a whole lot more to us if we could see what code you tried with.

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    

        If System.IO.File.Exists(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\GF_MAIN.log") Then
            TextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\GF_MAIN.log")
        Else
            MsgBox("File not found", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error")
        End If



    End Sub

Comment: i tried this and its work but for a specific file what i want is browsing to choose from many files

Comment: Edit your question and format that correctly. It's virtually incomprehensible in comment-form.

Comment: when i click the "browse" button I need to browse for a txt/xml file and place the data of that file in the text box.

Comment: Yeah, we already know that part.  Edit your question and post the code in the question, not as a comment, so that you can format it correctly and we can read it.

Comment: Have you debugged your code with a breakpoint to see where it's falling over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If think that the problem is in your if statement. Here is an example of what you can do:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("Your Path") = True Then
        TextBox1.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("Your Path")
    Else
        MsgBox("ERROR - File Not Found")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Notice the change I did in the If Statement. Hoped it helped.

Comment: Dim myFileDlog As New OpenFileDialog()
myFileDlog.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
myFileDlog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*" & _
"|Data Files (*.dat)|*.dat"
myFileDlog.FilterIndex = 2
myFileDlog.RestoreDirectory = True
If myFileDlog.ShowDialog() = _
DialogResult.OK Then
If Dir(myFileDlog.FileName) <> "" Then
MsgBox("File Exists: " & _
myFileDlog.FileName, _
                       MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Else
                MsgBox("File Not Found", _
                       MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End If
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = myFileDlog.FileName

Comment: this code show me the path of file....I need to show the data of the file.